# Windows Application C# strings combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, string, visual-studio, combobox

I'm trying to make a Windows application in Visual Studio.

In the `public Form1()`, I add some items to my ComboBox with `SelectComboBox.Items.Insert(0, "Text");` and create a string ex. `string NR0 = "__";` with a special song.

When I have selected an item in the ComboBox, and clicked on a select, I want the Windows Media Player to play the specific song in the string (ex. NR0) in the top.

I had tried to create a string in the code for the select button. `string ComboNow = "NR" + SelectComboBox.Items.Count.ToString();` and then changed the URL with `Player.URL = @ComboNow;`.

But then the player think the URL is the name of the string (ex. NR0).

Do you have any idea to solve this problem.

Thank you

---

The code is like below:

```
namespace Player
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SelectComboBox.Items.Insert(0, "First song");
            string NR0 = "URL to song";

            SelectComboBox.Items.Insert(1, "Second song");
            string NR1 = "URL to song";
        }

        private void SelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string[] value)
        {
            string ComboNow = "NR" + SelectComboBox.Items.Count.ToString();
            Player.URL = @ComboNow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't find more ways to do it, I have chosen my way. Thank you everybody, who had used time to help me. I'm a teenager from Denmark, so I'm sorry, if I have some problems with the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a List or an Array:

```
private List<string> songs = new List<string>();
//...
SelectComboBox.Items.Insert(0, "First song");
songs.Add("URL to song");
//...
Player.URL = songs[SelectComboBox.SelectedIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are explicitly putting these items into certain locations, I would do something like create a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> Songs
{
    get
    {
        return new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                { 0, "url of first song" },
                { 1, "url of second song" }
            };
    }
}
```

You can then just get the URL like so:

```
string playerURL = Songs[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
```

Note this will only work because you are putting the items into the combo box in a particular order, if this is not what you want in the future, this won't be for you.

Comment: @Downvoter, please explain. Can't learn without being told what is wrong with it!

Comment: Thank you very much, from start I had a long list with check number if else, check again a new number.